# what is the purpose of pullup and pulldown resistor in i2c bus

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, i2c

For i2c communication either pullup resistor or pull down resistor is connected to the i2c bus line.

what is the purpose of these pullup and pulldown resistor and how to decide which resistor need to connect whether pullup or pull down resistor???

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about electrical engineering, not computer programming.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about electrical engineering

Answer (score 3):

i think you mean Resistor.

the pull down and pull up resistors are used to keep the pin in a stable state when e.g. no signal is on the line.

you can imagine like allways saying 00000 or 11111.

if you dont use pull down/up resistors your input can toggle caused by environmental noise etc.

the resistor has a very high value, so every other signal on the line wont be affected by the resitor

Comment: Mr tecjam, Thanks a lot for your responce.  if it is used for stable the output then when we should use pullup and when we should use pulldown resistor???

Comment: it depends on design: e.g. you could define that 1 = HIGH and 0 = LOW (positiv logic). You also can define, that if nothing is send, the line should be 0, so you need a pull-DOWN. i2c uses also positiv logic (1=HIGH, 0=LOW) but let the line HIGH on IDLE. the reason is that in most cases it is easier to have only one V+ connection and let the devices pull-DOWN the line to ground if they want send data so they use pull-UP.

Answer (score 0):

In general, a pull down resistor is required to bring a pin to a defined voltage when the effects of near and far field interference are exacerbated  such as when the pin has a high input impedance and is left floating. In order to read a 0 on the pin, it has to be pulled to 0 in these conditions, because if it is left floating, you will read an arbitrary value. The lower resistance between the input and the place of 0 potential, the lower the magnitude of the noise such that it fits within the noise margin of correctly reading a digital 0.

Without a pull down resistor, the input would typically be high-Z if the input impedance is in the realm of megaohms. High-Z means that the pin is not pulled high or low, and the input impedance is high enough to see high enough voltage noise that the state does not fit within the margins of the defined logic levels.

The induced current amplitude is:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

V<sub>s</sub> is the noise amplitude, V<sub>R</sub> is the induced voltage i.e. the voltage over the resistance of the load and V<sub>c</sub> is the voltage over the coupling capacitor. X<sub>c</sub> is the capacitive reactance of the coupling capacitor and R is the resistance of the load.

In a typical scenario, parasitic capacitance is on the order of pico farads, meaning the capacitive reactance is very large. A plot of V<sub>R</sub> with respect to R of 10 pF at 60Hz with a 1V noise source reveals the following:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Adding the pull down resistor in parallel reduces the R of the load such that the parallel resistance is smaller than resistance of the smaller resistor (the pulldown), so the resistance of a 100Ω pulldown and a 2MΩ original load is <100Ω, which yields 380nV noise instead of 7.54mV of noise that you get without the pull down resistor, from the 1V noise source. Arduino input impedance of 100MΩ gives 0.3528V.

As you increase R, V<sub>R</sub> always tends asymptotically to V<sub>s</sub>, as you can tell from the equation for V<sub>s</sub>:

[image]

The introduction of a pull down resistor reduces the effects of reactive and radiative coupling.

[image]

Switch open: the pin is pulled to 0, no power loss. Switch closed, the pin is 5V, with the correct current for V/R2, power loss in pull down

[image]

Switch open: the pin is pulled to very near 5V, 4.9999... And current is very near R4. Power loss much less than pull down. Switch closed: the pin is pulled to 0v because 0 resistance and R4 in parallel is 0, so all of the drop is over R3. Power loss over R3.

[image]

Here, because the pin is High–Z, the impedance is comparable to that of the parasitic capacitive reactances in the circuit and therefore the voltage at the input can fluctuate well above zero. It can also act as an antenna, and the induced voltage will be high as the impedance to ground is high.

[image]

In the pull down scenario, the impedance to the ground is low, meaning the potential division between the parasitic capacitance and the circuit is such that the voltage at the pin is negligible. Similarly, the induced voltage through radiation is far less because more current is induced, and also the induced power dissipates mainly over the pull down resistor.